# Boost Graph: filtered_graph contains edge or vertex?

Tags: boost

In a `boost::filtered_graph`, is it possible to pass an edge- or vertex descriptor of the underlying graph to check it the descriptor is part of the filtered graph as well?

Use case: I have a r-tree containing all vertices from the underlying graph, and I want to filter out all the nodes (yielded by a spatial query) which do not belong to the filtered graph.

I don't want to deal with the predicates after constructing the `filtered_graph`. The predicate function objects are private members of the `filtered_graph`, so I wonder, if there is a way to access them with a non-member function.

Comment: The `private:` above them is commented, so I guess you should be able to use them. [Latest version](http://www.boost.org/boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp), [version 1.38](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp).

Comment: @llonesmiz How could I have overlooked that ... thank you, should work then as a "quick solution".